# cURL: how to enter a URL from a variable with special characters

Tags: bash, curl

I have the URL in a variable, which is read from another place. This variable has the `?` and `&` characters. If I enter the whole URL between single or double quotes, it works fine. But if I enter the variable, curl complains the URL has illegal characters. How do I circumvent this?

PS.: I also tried to replace `?` and `&` with `%3F` and `%26` but it didn't work.

Example:

```
$ echo "$location"
https://example.com/dothis?param1=something&param2=somethingelse
$ curl "$location" -o /dev/null > /dev/null
curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL
$ curl "https://example.com/dothis?param1=something&param2=somethingelse" -o /dev/null > /dev/null
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  126k    0  126k    0     0  13974      0 --:--:--  0:00:09 --:--:-- 32272
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce this here. Could be that there are invisible characters in your URL. Try again, maybe, after re-defining your `location` variable.

Comment: Try `echo "$location" | LC_ALL=C cat -vet` to see if there are any invisible characters in the variable. Note that the `-e` will make it add a "$" to the end of the line; anything other than that is a potential problem.

Comment: That's correct @GordonDavisson. `cat -A` showed a `^M` before `$`. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be some invisible chars. So try

```
printf '%s' "$location" | hexdump -C
```

Comment: you were so right. There was a final character represented by a dot in hexdump, doing this to compare worked. Thank you, `curl "${location::${#location}-1}" -o /dev/null`